# Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles

Tags: php, string

No termino de aclararme sobre la forma de combinar variables y cadenas escritas directamente.

Vamos a usar la variable `$test`:

```
$test="prueba";
```

#### Caso 1.-

Encerrar la variable en comillas dobles `" "` funciona:

```
echo "Esto es una $test";
```

**`Resultado`:**

```
Esto es una prueba
```

#### Caso 2.-

Encerrar la variable en comillas simples `' '` no funciona:

```
echo 'Esto es una $test';
```

**`Resultado`:**

```
Esto es una $test
```

Al parecer, cuando usamos comillas dobles el valor de `$test` es reconocido, pero no lo es si usamos comillas simples.

Pero... probemos con arrays.

---

Trabajaremos con este array:

```
$arr=array(array("id"=>1, "nombre"=>"Pedro"), array("id"=>2, "nombre"=>"Juan"));
```

#### Caso 3.-

Leer `$arr` aplicando el mismo criterio del **Caso 1**:

```
foreach ($arr as $row){
     echo "ID: $row['id']\n";
}
```

**`Resultado:`**

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''
> (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Y, según comenta @Marcos al pie de esta pregunta, en este caso se podría hacer también esto:

```
echo "ID: $row[id]\n";
```

Es decir, sin las comillas simples. Como nota adicional, no se puede acceder a valores en una sub-profundidad, es decir que esto no sería válido:

```
echo "ID: $row[prop][valor]\n";
```

#### Caso 4.-

Bueno, vamos a invertir las comillas:

```
foreach ($arr as $row){
     echo 'ID: $row["id"]\n';
}
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
ID: $row["id"]\n
ID: $row["id"]\n
```

¿Parece que no se puede aplicar el mismo procedimiento del `echo` más arriba cuando leemos un array?

¿Será la única alternativa dejar fuera la variable que se captura con `row`?

```
foreach ($arr as $row){
     echo 'ID: '.$row["id"].'\n';

     //O bien:
     echo "ID: ".$row["id"]."\n";

}
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
ID: 1
ID: 2
```

#### La pregunta

Vistos los casos más arriba, me pregunto ¿a qué se debe que el echo no reconozca las variables entre comillas simples y por qué el método del caso 1 no funciona en el caso 3?

Planteo la pregunta porque siempre me confundo cuando tengo que usar variables combinadas con cadenas escritas a mano.

Comment: Una solución al `Caso 3` es hacer el `echo` así: `echo "ID: $row[id]\n";` (_sin las comillas simples_). Como nota adicional, **no se puede acceder a valores en una _sub-profundidad_**, es decir `echo "ID: $row[prop][valor]\n";`, no es válido.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Te voy a contestar según el *[manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)*, un literal de tipo cadena se puede especificar de cuatro formas diferentes:

- [entrecomillado simple](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)
- [entrecomillado doble](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)
- [sintaxis heredoc](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
- [sintaxis nowdoc (desde PHP 5.3.0)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

*Para no extender mucho veamos los primeros dos a tu pregunta.*

**Entrecomillado simple**

La forma más sencilla para declarar una cadena es usando las comillas simples (el carácter `'`).

> **Nota:** A diferencia de las sintaxis de entrecomillado doble `""` y heredoc `<<<EOD`, las `variables` y las sentencias de escape para caracteres especiales no se expandirán cuando estén incluidas dentro de una cadena  entre comillas simples `''`.

*Ejemplo:*

```
<?php
echo 'Esto es una cadena sencilla';

echo 'También se pueden incluir nuevas líneas en
un string de esta forma, ya que es
correcto hacerlo así';

// Resultado: Arnold una vez dijo: "I'll be back"
echo 'Arnold una vez dijo: "I\'ll be back"';

// Resultado: Ha borrado C:\*.*?
echo 'Ha borrado C:\\*.*?';

// Resultado: Ha borrado C:\*.*?
echo 'Ha borrado C:\*.*?';

// Resultado: Esto no se expandirá: \n una nueva línea
echo 'Esto no se expandirá: \n una nueva línea';

// Resultado: Las variables $tampoco se $expandirán
echo 'Las variables $tampoco se $expandirán';
?>
```

**Entrecomillado doble**

Si una cadena está formado con comillas dobles ("), PHP interpretará las siguientes secuencias de escape como caracteres especiales:

*Caracteres escapados:*

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|  Secuencia  |                    Significado                       |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+    
|     \n      |   avance de línea (LF o 0x0A (10) en ASCII)          |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \r      |   retorno de carro (CR o 0x0D (13) en ASCII)         |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \t      |   tabulador horizontal (HT o 0x09 (9) en ASCII)      |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \v      |   tabulador vertical (VT o 0x0B (11) en ASCII)       | 
|             |   (desde PHP 5.2.5)                                  |    
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+   
|     \e      |   escape (ESC o 0x1B (27) en ASCII)                  | 
|             |   (desde PHP 5.4.4)                                  |    
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \f      |   avance de página (FF o 0x0C (12) en ASCII)         | 
|             |   (desde PHP 5.2.5)                                  |    
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \\      |   barra invertida                                    |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \$      |   signo de dólar                                     |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     \"      |   comillas dobles                                    |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| \[0-7]{1,3} |   la secuencia de caracteres que coincida con la     |
|             |   expresión regular es un carácter en notación octal,|
|             |   que silenciosamente desborda para encajar en un    |
|             |   byte (p.ej. "\400" === "\000")                     | 
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| \x[0-9A-Fa- |   la secuencia de caracteres que coincida con la     |
| f]{1,2}     |   expresión regular es un carácter en notación       |
|             |   hexadecimal                                        |        
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| \u{[0-9A-Fa |   la secuencia de caracteres que coincida con la     |
| -f]+}       |   expresión regular es un punto de código de Unicode,|
|             |   la cual será imprimida al string como dicha        | 
|             |   representación UTF-8 del punto de código (añadido  | 
|             |   en PHP 7.0.0)                                      |        
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

> **Nota:** La característica más importante del entrecomillado doble `""` de una cadena es el hecho de que se expanden los nombres de las variables.

**Análisis de variables**

Cuando una cadena es especificado mediante comillas dobles `""` o mediante heredoc `<<<EOT`, las variables que haya dentro de dicho string se analizarán.

Existen dos tipos de sintaxis: una *simple* y otra *compleja*. La sintaxis simple es la más empleada y práctica. Proporciona una forma de embeber una `variable`, un valor de un `array` o una propiedad de un `object` dentro de una `cadena` con el mínimo esfuerzo.

La sintaxis compleja puede ser reconocida por las llaves que delimitan la expresión.

**Sintaxis simple**

Si se encuentra un signo de dólar (`$`), el analizador tomará el mayor número de símbolos para formar un nombre de *variable válido*. Delimitar el nombre de la variable con llaves permite especificar explícitamente el final del nombre.

*Ejemplo:*

```
<?php
$jugo = "manzana";

 echo "Él tomó algo de jugo de $jugo.".PHP_EOL; 
 // Inválido. "s" es un carácter válido para un nombre de variable, pero la variable es $jugo.
 echo "Él tomó algo de jugo hecho de $jugos.";
 // Válido. Explícitamente especifica el final del nombre de la variable encerrándolo entre llaves:
 echo "Él tomó algo de jugo hecho de ${jugo}s."
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

```
Él tomó algo de jugo de manzana.
Él tomó algo de jugo hecho de .
Él tomó algo de jugo hecho de manzanas.
```

De forma parecida, se puede analizar el índice de un `array` o la propiedad de un `object`.

```
$jugos = array("manzana", "naranja", "koolaid1" => "púrpura");

echo "Él tomó algo de jugo de $jugos[0].".PHP_EOL;
echo "Él tomó algo de jugo de $jugos[1].".PHP_EOL;
echo "Él tomó algo de jugo $jugos[koolaid1].".PHP_EOL;

class persona {
    public $john = "John Smith";
    public $jane = "Jane Smith";
    public $robert = "Robert Paulsen";

    public $smith = "Smith";
}

$persona = new persona();

echo "$persona->john tomó algo de jugo de $jugos[0].".PHP_EOL;
echo "$persona->john entonces dijo hola a $persona->jane.".PHP_EOL;
echo "La esposa de $persona->john saludó a $persona->robert.".PHP_EOL;
echo "$persona->robert saludó a los dos $persona->smiths."; // No funcionará
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

```
Él tomó algo de jugo de manzana.
Él tomó algo de jugo de naranja.
Él tomó algo de jugo púrpura.
John Smith tomó algo de jugo de manzana.
John Smith entonces dijo hola a Jane Smith.
La esposa de John Smith saludó a Robert Paulsen.
Robert Paulsen saludó a los dos .
```

**Sintaxis compleja (llaves)**

Esta sintaxis no se llama compleja porque sea compleja, sino porque permite el empleo de expresiones complejas.

Cualquier *variable escalar*, *elemento de array* o *propiedad de objeto* con una representación de *tipo cadena* puede ser incluido a través de esta sintaxis. Simplemente se escribe la expresión del mismo modo en que aparecería por fuera de la cadena, y delimitándola con `{ y }`. Dado que `{` no puede ser escapado, esta sintaxis será reconocida únicamente cuando el `$` siga inmediatamente al `{`. Utilice `{\$` para obtener un `{$ literal`.

*Algunos ejemplos:*

```
<?php
// Mostrar todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$genial = 'fantástico';

// No funciona, muestra: Esto es { fantástico}
echo "Esto es { $genial}";

// Funciona, muestra: Esto es fantástico
echo "Esto es {$genial}";

// Funciona
echo "Este cuadrado tiene {$cuadrado->width}00 centímetros de lado.";


// Funciona, las claves entre comillas sólo funcionan usando la sintaxis de llaves
echo "Esto funciona: {$arr['clave']}";


// Funciona
echo "Esto funciona: {$arr[4][3]}";

// Esto no funciona por la misma razón que $foo[bar] es incorrecto fuera de un string.
// En otras palabras, aún funcionaría, pero solamente porque PHP primero busca una
// constante llamada foo; se emitirá un error de nivel E_NOTICE
// (constante no definida).
echo "Esto está mal: {$arr[foo][3]}"; 

// Funciona. Cuando se usan arrays multidimensionales, emplee siempre llaves que delimiten
// a los arrays cuando se encuentre dentro de un string
echo "Esto funciona: {$arr['foo'][3]}";

// Funciona.
echo "Esto funciona: " . $arr['foo'][3];

echo "Esto también funciona: {$obj->valores[3]->nombre}";

echo "Este es el valor de la variable llamada $nombre: {${$nombre}}";

echo "Este es el valor de la variable llamada por el valor devuelto por getNombre(): {${getNombre()}}";

echo "Este es el valor de la variable llamada por el valor devuelto por \$objeto->getNombre(): {${$objeto->getNombre()}}";

//No funciona, muestra: Esto es el valor devuelto por getNombre(): {getNombre()}
echo "Esto es el valor devuelto por getNombre(): {getNombre()}";
?>
```

> Estas reglas la encontré en el *manual PHP* como notas aportadas por otros usuarios, que me parecen que puede contestar tu pregunta:

1. Siempre use cadenas de comillas dobles (`""`) para la concatenación.
2. Ponga sus variables en `"Esto es una notación {$variable}"`, porque es el método más rápido que todavía permite expansiones complejas como `"This {$var['foo']} es {$obj->awesome()}!"`. No puedes hacer eso con el estilo `"${var}"`.
3. Siéntase libre de usar cadenas de comillas simples `''` para cadenas **TOTALMENTE literales** como *claves* / *valores de matrices*, *valores de variables*, etc., ya que son un bit TINY más rápido cuando se desean cadenas literales no analizadas. Pero tuve que hacer mil millones de iteraciones para encontrar una diferencia mensurable del 1,55%. Así que la única razón real por la que consideraría el uso de cadenas de una sola comilla para mis literales es para la *limpieza del código*, para hacer que sea muy claro que la cadena es literal.

*100 millones de iteraciones:*

```
    $outstr = 'literal' . $n . $data . $int . $data . $float . $n;
    63608ms (34.7% slower)

    $outstr = "literal$n$data$int$data$float$n";
    47218ms (fastest)

    $outstr =<<<EOS
    literal$n$data$int$data$float$n
    EOS;
    47992ms (1.64% slower)
```

Ver más [resultados de iteraciones](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#120160).
Fuente [Cadenas de caracteres (Strings)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta excelente respuesta.

Comment: No hay de que, ha sido un placer @A.Cedano . Un saludo.

Answer (score 7):

Las comillas simples son para **cadenas literales**: no reemplazan referencias a variables por sus valores, ni escapan caracteres.

```
$literal = 'hola, $nombre'; // hola, $nombre
$literal = 'hola, {$row->name}'; // hola, {$row->name}
$literal = 'columna \t columna'; // columna \t columna
```

Mientras que las comillas dobles son para **cadenas escapadas**: aceptan variables, referencias (entre llaves, como muestro más abajo) y caracteres escapados con contrabarra:

```
$escapada = "hola, $nombre"; // hola, Juan
$escapada = "hola, {$row->name}"; // hola, Juan
$escapada = "columna \t columna"; // columna          columna
```

Siempre que sea posible usá comillas simples, porque son más rápidas y seguras, a menos de que necesites escapar valores.

Si necesitás meter comillas dobles dentro de una cadena escapada, sencillamente las escapás:

```
$escapada = "Hola, $nombre, el símbolo de la comilla doble es \", ¿entiendes?";
// Hola, Juan, el símbolo de la comilla doble es ", ¿entiendes?
```

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero revisa las comillas de tu segundo ejemplo. Creo que se te paso sin querer. Un saludo.

Comment: Welp, editado. Gracias :)