# Hola tengo un problema en una pagina php con una consulta INSERT

Tags: php, html

Tengo mi pagina php en la primera parte de la pagina tengo la declaración de las variables y su almacenamiento con el "name" que les coloque en la pagina html

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';
//recir los datos y almacenarlos en las variables
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$cuenta = $_POST["cuenta"];
$idsemgrupo = $_POST["idsemgrupo"];
$curp = $_POST["curp"];

después hice la consulta insertar que es esta
//consulta para insertar 
$insertar = "INSERT INTO alumnos( id, nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, clave, telefono, cuenta, idsemgrupo, curp) VALUES (NULL, "$nombre", "$apellidos", "$correo", "$usuario", $clave, $telefono, "$cuenta", $idsemgrupo, "$curp")";

//ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if(!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al insertar Registros';
}
else{
    'Registros insertdos correctamente';
}

//cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

y me marca error aquí

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$nombre' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\registrar.php on line 16

si me puden ayudar se los agradecería gracias

Comment: POR QUE pones el id como NULL? es auto increment y primary key en tu base de datos?

Comment: De echo se lo quite pero aun asi me sigue marcando error en lo mismo

Comment: Cuando tienes una cadena con comillas dobles, debes usar comillas simples dentro para indicar cadenas/strings dentro de esa cadena (puedes leer más [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/250) o directamente en la [documentación oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)). Además, te recomiendo que leas sobre [inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250), porque este código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques. Y lee [ask] y completa el [tour], esta pregunta podría mejorarse con los consejos que encontrarás allí.

Comment: si las coloco con comillas simple me marca aun mas una serie de errores

Comment: Has comprobado que todos los datos los recibes correctamente antes de hacer la consulta a la BD ?

Comment: Si un sin fin de veces

Comment: @JuanCarlosOliveraGomez ¿Cuál es la cadena que te queda cuando pones las comillas simples?¿qué errores te salen? ¿Qué tipos tienen cada columnas?¿falla con todos los valores o solo con algunos? Añade más información a la pregunta. Todo este problema se solucionaría si usarás sentencias preparadas en lugar de concatenar cadenas (qué es una muy mala práctica y lleva a código de baja calidad) y además harías tu código más robusto y seguro (porque ahora mismo es vulnerable a inyección SQL que es un problema muy grave de seguridad).

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que entre otros detalles, te código es incorrecto por los siguientes motivos

1. No estas metiendo las variables de modo correcto, incluso algunas las pones con comillas y otras sin comillas, ni siquiera las estás concatenando

Así como te lo pongo te debería de funcionar

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO alumnos(nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, 
clave, telefono, cuenta, idsemgrupo, curp) VALUES ('".$nombre."', 
'".$apellidos."', '".$correo."', '".$usuario."', '".$clave."', 
'".$telefono."', '".$cuenta."', '".$idsemgrupo."', '".$curp."')";
```

> También te comento que si tu columna id, en tu base de datos es auto
>   incremental y primary key, no necesitas meterla en ningún lado de tu
>   query, solo si cumple esas 2 características

Comment: ya lo hice y me carca el mismo error

Comment: @JuanCarlosOliveraGomez seguro cambiaste toda la línea como te indico?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tu_db', 'root', 'tu_pass');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}



if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])){
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre, apellido) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido)");
    $add->bindValue(':nombre', ($_POST['nombre']));
    $add->bindValue(':apellido', ($_POST['apellido']));
    $add->execute();
    echo "El alumno fue agregado <a href='../'>volver</a>";
}
else{
    echo "Ingresar datos <a href='../'>volver</a>";
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="nombre" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="text" name="apellido" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
<button name="agregar">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Asi como esta deberia funcionar. Es lo que uso para trabajar todos los dias.
Cuendo tenes que agregar algo, tenes que declara todo.
Isset determina si la variable esta definida o no, despues empty se fija si una variable esta vacia. Despues uso sentencias preparadas: http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Espero te ayude