# Imprimir variables reservadas de PHP, en comillas dobles

Tags: php

He trabajado constantemente en comillas simples, que me he olvidado completamente el uso de las comillas dobles.

Hoy tenia estilos en un archivo, entre otros como esto:

```
echo '#parent';
```

y me toco migrar a

```
echo "#parent";
```

Y ahora cómo puedo hacer funcionar las variables reservadas de php en doble comillas

```
$row = "www";
echo "base64_encode($row)";
```

En comillas simples lo realizaba de la siguiente forma:

```
$row = "www";
echo ''.base64_encode($row).'';
```

Comment: Puedes hacer así `echo "base64_encode(".$row.")";`

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Intenta colocar tu función directamente: echo base64_encode($row);

Comment: No entiendo para que quieres meter la función dentro de las comillas ¿?

Comment: ¿Alguna de las respuestas resolvieron tu duda? Si es así agradeceríamos que la marcaras como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar prácticamente, realizando lo mismo, la diferencia es que se agrega doble comilla:

```
$row = "www.example.com";
echo "".base64_encode($row)."";
```

Puedes observar la [demostración](https://ideone.com/0QwqwM)

Adjunto fuente sobre uso variado de doble y simple comilla.

- [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles)

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tendría hacer esto : `echo "".base64_encode($row)."";` y no esto sencillamente: `echo base64_encode($row);`

Comment: @A.Cedano Bueno yo simplemente me base a la pregunta del usuario, no sabemos el uso completo de su código, pero en base de la pregunta es porque debe existir algo no sencillamente, por lo que observo, indica que en su código existían estilos dentro de las etiquetas y propiedades de `#` `id` de elementos a lo mejor está mezclando el código `PHP` con `API`, `javascript` o `jQuery`, pistas por los elementos mencionados en su pregunta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la base de que tratas de hacer:

```
<?php
$row = "www";
echo ''.base64_encode($row).'';
```

El equivalente directo con comillas dobles sería:

```
<?php
$row = "www";
echo "".base64_encode($row)."";
```

Una cadena vacía de comillas simples, `''`, se puede representar igualmente con comillas dobles, `""`.

Aún así la forma correcta (sin concatenar innecesariamente cadenas vacías) de hacerlo sería:

```
<?php
$row = "www";
echo base64_encode($row);
```

Esto es debido a que en tu código con comillas simples estás concatenando una cadena vacía antes y después de la llamada a `base64_encode()`, siendo completamente innecesario hacerlo ya que `echo` puede recibir directamente la salida de `base64_encode()` sin necesidad de hacer nada más.

En cuanto al intento que has hecho:

```
<?php
$row = "www";
echo "base64_encode($row)";
```

No es posible realizar la ejecución de una función (o método) dentro de las comillas dobles. En [la documentación de PHP](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing) podrás consultar que únicamente se pueden interpretar valores de variables o propiedades de clase.