# Problema para pasar valores por URL (GET) en PHP

Tags: php, sql, variables, post, get

Intento hacer lo siguiente:

Desde una consulta, creo una tabla, a la que a una opción, estoy añadiendo un enlace para imprimir un pdf,

```
$indices .= '<tr>
                    <td>' .$row[id_presupuesto]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[fecha]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[referencia]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[ncomercial]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[precio_final]. ' €</td>
                    <td>' .$row[estado]. '</td>
                    <td><a href="pdf/documentos/presupuesto.php?id=$idd"><i class="fas fa-eye imprimir"></i></a></td>
                    <td><i id="'.$row[id_presupuesto].'" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
                </tr>';
```

En concreto, es esta línea:

```
<td><a href="pdf/documentos/presupuesto.php?id=idd"><i class="fas fa-eye imprimir"></i></a></td>
```

He añadido toda la variable `$indices` para que quede claro, que el código es HTML dentro de PHP, sobre todo por el tema de las comillas.

Ahora mismo, en la URL, me pasa `?id=$idd`
¿Como puedo hacer que saque el `"id"` correcto?

- Añadir que `$idd`, proviene de:

`$idd = $row[id_presupuesto];`

Saludos.

Comment: Las otras columnas te muestran los valores correctos?

Comment: Lee [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/250). Esto es un problema por intentar poner variables dentro de comillas simples en lugar de dobles.

Comment: Dejaria href="pdf/documentos/presupuesto.php?id=<?=$row[id_presupuesto]?>"

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, la solución era tan simple como modificar esto: href="pdf/documentos/presupuesto.php?id='.$idd.'">