# Sustituir una variable dentro de un campo en una tabla

Tags: php

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una tabla con varios campos, en uno de ellos de tipo `longtext`, el usuario guarda un formato de envío de correo, por ejemplo

Hola `$nombre`
Te envío este correo de prueba a $nombre

hasta aquí todo bien, el programa en php funciona perfectamente y envía el correo, el problema me aparece al querer sustituir la variable $nombre, por el nombre del destinatario, no me lo hace, sino que me envía el correo tal como aparece en el ejemplo y yo quiero que me sustituya `$nombre.`

Me podrían ayudar.

Este es el código

```
<?php
include_once('../include/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    $cuerpo_correo
</body>
</html>";

//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

$mail->From       = "info@gcnetonline.es";
$mail->FromName   = "Gcnet";

$mail->Subject    = $asunto_correo;

$mail->AltBody    = "Si no puedes ver este mensaje, por favor utiliza un programa de correo compatible HTML."; // optional, comment out and test

//$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->MsgHTML(utf8_decode($body));


$mail->AddAddress($email1, "Gcnet");



if(!$mail->Send()) {
//  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
//  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
<head>
  <title>Gcnet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

La variable cuerpo de correo la sustituye bien. Les pongo también un ejemplo de lo que hay en la variable $cuerpo_mensaje que a su vez es recogida de la BD.

Este correo se le envía a $nombre porque estás dado de alta en  nuestras newsletter.

Esta sería la variable $asunto_correo, el problema es que no me sustituye la otra variable $nombre, que está dentro de `$asunto_correo`

Espero haberme explicado bien

Hola, esta es el código que hace la llamada:
if (isset($_POST['enviar_correo'])) {

```
$tipo_plantilla = $_POST['tipo_plantilla'];
$asunto_correo = $_POST['asunto_correo'];
$cuerpo_correo = $_POST['p_plantilla'];
$enviado = $_POST['enviado'];
$codigo_cupon = $_POST['codigo_cupon'];
$fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
$fecha_final = $_POST['fecha_final'];
$descuento = $_POST['descuento'];

$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$ip1 = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

if($codigo_cupon != "")
{
    $result_clientes_tmp = mysql_query("Select * From clientes_tmp ",$con);

    while($row_clientes_tmp=mysql_fetch_array($result_clientes_tmp)) {

        $codigo_cliente = $row_clientes_tmp['cod_cli'];
        $email1 = $row_clientes_tmp['email'];

        //se inserta el cupón
        $result1 = mysql_query("Insert into cupones(cupon, dto, id_cli, fecha, fecha_envio, fecha_vto)
```

values('$codigo_cupon','$descuento','$codigo_cliente','$fecha_inicio','$hoy','$fecha_final')");

```
    }
}


if($enviado == 1)
{
    $p_enviado = 1;
}else
{
    $p_enviado = 0;
}


$result1 = mysql_query("Insert into correos(id_plantilla, asunto_correo, cuerpo_correo, enviado, hash, ip, fecha, id_cli)
```

values('$tipo_plantilla','$asunto_correo','$cuerpo_correo','$p_enviado','$cadena','$ip1','$hoy','$id_cli')");

```
//se averigua el id del correo
$result_correos = mysql_query("Select * From correos WHERE hash='$cadena'",$con);

if(mysql_num_rows($result_correos)>0)
{
    $row_correos = mysql_fetch_array($result_correos);

    $id_correo = $row_correos['id'];

}

//se insertan los clientes a los que se les va a enviar el correo
$result_insert = mysql_query("Select * From clientes_tmp ",$con);

while($row_insert=mysql_fetch_array($result_insert)) {

    $nombre = $row_insert['nombre'];
    $email1 = $row_insert['email'];

    $result1 = mysql_query("Insert into correos_clientes(id_correo, nombre, email, ip, id_cli)
```

values('$id_correo','$nombre','$email1','$ip1','$id_cli')");

```
    if($p_enviado == 1)
    {
        include("sendcorreos.php");
    }
}
```

las variables las recojo, mediante POST y luego mediante un include hago la llamada a la función que envía el correo. El correo lo envía bien, sin ningún problema. Lo que me pasa es que esa variable a su vez tiene una variable, que es recogida desde la BD y el la que quiero sustituir.
Para que me entiendan, es un campo de la BD, que el usuario personaliza y lo que quiero es que le envíe ese campo (esto lo hace bien), pero que a su vez lo personalice para cada usuario. En la BD, hay por ejemplo lo siguiente: Hola $nombre, te damos la bienvenida, lo que quiero es que la variable nombre se cambie por el nombre de la persona, y la variable $cuerpo_correo, también la recojo desde la BD, no es fija, por eso no puedo usar el echo "Hola $nombre";, por a su vez la variable la recojo de la BD, es decir, lo que quiero es que dentro de la variable me sustituya otra variable, es para hacer un sistema personalizado de correo de bienvenida. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Si agregas el código te podremos ayudar!

Comment: Ya te he añadido el código, gracias

Comment: no se ve donde asignas el valor a la variable `$asunto_correo`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Como dice @YoAlbert, debes mostrar cómo creas la variable `$asunto_correo`. Por lo que dices, sospecho que la estás escribiendo así: `$asunto_correo='Hola $nombre Te envío este correo de prueba a $nombre';` ... para usar variables de forma efectiva dentro de una cadena, debes usar comillas dobles, o sea: **`$asunto_correo="Hola $nombre Te envío este correo de prueba a $nombre";`** Para más detalles [puedes revisar esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967), donde se profundiza sobre lo que te está ocurriendo en este caso.

Comment: Hola, esta es el código que hace la llamada:

Comment: Básicamente lo que quiero es un sistema de envío de correo automatizado, y recojo el contenido de la BD y quiero sustituir una variable dentro de otra para personalizarlo. Ese es el problema que esa última no me la sustituye