# No funciona comparador !=

Tags: php

Estoy intentando reconocer cuando un registro de mi BD no coincide con una palabra.

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien cuando $cliente es igual a **Dia**, pero no funciona si $cliente es igual a **diA**

```html
   elseif (strpos($cliente, 'Dia') !== false or strpos($cliente, 'plaza') !== false) {
              echo "background:#c31434;";
              }
```

He probado a hacerlo al revés y tampoco funciona

```html
elseif (strpos($cliente, 'Dia') == true or strpos($cliente, 'plaza') == true) {
                  echo "background:#c31434;";
                  }
```

También he probado a hacerlo como dice @Hector Lopez de esta forma, y tampoco me funciona igual que en el caso de arriba

```html
elseif ($cliente == 'dia' || $cliente == 'plaza') {
                  echo "background:#c31434;";
                  }
```

Este es mi if completo

```html
<?php if(strpos($cliente, 'Lupa') !== false or strpos($cliente, 'lupa') !== false or strpos($cliente, 'Tifer') !== false){
                  echo "background:#1474c3;";
                  }
                  elseif ($cliente =='dia' || $cliente =='plaza') {
                  echo "background:#c31434;";
                  }
                  else{
                  echo "background:#778998;";
                  };
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema es ese `or` que has puesto, cámbialo por `||`

Comment: Lo he cambiado y el problema sigue.

Comment: `analizo si $cliente es exactamente igual a "Dia" y funciona bien` ¿Puedes poner el código que funciona? Y.... ¿estás seguro de que el `elseif` se ejecuta (qué no esté ejecutándose la rama principal del `if`?

Comment: En tu caso quizá estés necesitando [la función **`strcasecmp`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strcasecmp.php). De todos modos, pon el bloque `if` completo, pues sospecho que tu código es *optimizable*. Y, evita usar *codesnippets*  con código que no se pueda probar, ya que su finalidad es poner código cuyos resultados podamos ver. Si es código como PHP es mejor ponerlo usando únicamente **`{ }`**. Gracias.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con el if completo. Es un poco arcaico pero aprendo según voy escribiendo código y consultando por aquí

Comment: por que no llevas todo a mayuscula y comparas?

Comment: solucionalo con un `strpos(strtoupper($cliente) , "DIA")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo resolvería esto de una forma más *flexible*, creando un array en el que las claves serían el valor del color, y cada clave tenga un sub-array con los valores a buscar. De este modo no necesitarás hacer tantos `if` y si en un futuro hay que incorporar más valores/colores sólo modificas el array y el código seguiría funcionando sólo.

Para la comparación, en vez de `strpos`, usas **`strripos`**, que hace lo mismo, pero es *case insensitive*, o sea, insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Veamos:

```
$cliente="diA";
$arrColors=array('#1474c3'=>array('lupa','tifer'),"#c31434"=>array('dia','plaza'));
/*Valor por defecto*/
$bgColor="#778998";
foreach ($arrColors as $k=>$arrValues){
    if (is_array($arrValues)){
        foreach ($arrValues as $value) {
            if(stripos($cliente, $value) !== false){
                $bgColor=$k;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "background:$bgColor;";
```

**Salida:**

```
background:#c31434;
```

Ahora:

- prueba tú mismo con otros valores
- plantéate una **evolución** del código. Imagina que se requiere ahora buscar el valor `'amarillo'` y asignarle el color de fondo `#FFFF00` ... Sólo tendrías que agregar esto a `$arrColors`: **`'#FFFF00'=>array('amarillo')`**

Comment: Funciona a las mil maravillas, sólo un pequeño detalle. En el echo "background:$bgColor;"; lo he puesto de esta manera echo "background:" . $bgColor; Mil gracias

Comment: @Tefef, me alegro de que te haya funcionado. En PHP, cuando usas comillas dobles `"` puedes incluir variables dentro. También funciona concatenando con el punto... [Puedes consultar esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967) para más detalles.