# Strings con comillas simples o dobles

Tags: php

Cuál es la diferencia entre utilizar comillas simples o comillas dobles?

```
$tipoFile = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
$mimeFile = "text/plain";
$ruta = FILE_DIR . "/carga/";
$formato = 'CUOTAS'.$_SESSION['anio'].".csv";
```

Pues en el manual de [php.net](http://php.net/) utilizan comillas simples y/o dobles en muchos de sus ejemplos.

Comment: Deberias reformular la pregunta; tal y como está, estás demandando *opiniones*. Hay diferencias y usos claros para cada tipo de cadena. Creo que ya hay hasta preguntas sobre ello.

Comment: Coincido con @Trauma. Tal y como planteas la pregunta, una posible respuesta estaría basada en meras opiniones. No sé si [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967) y sus respuestas te puedan ayudar a aclarar algunas dudas más concretas sobre el problema de las comillas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas comillas, simples y dobles sirven para especificar strings, la direferencia es que la comilla simple especifca cadenas literalmente y la comillas dobles especifican strings con algunas conversiones: variables por su valor y valores escapados.

```
    $mundo = 'pepe';

    echo 'hola $mundo';
    // hola $mundo

    echo "hola $mundo";
    // hola pepe

    echo "Realiza un salto de linea al final\n";
    echo 'No realiza salto de linea al final\n';
```

Más información en la [documentacion.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Úsalas según convenga ;-)