# Ayuda con variables php entre comillas y phpmailer

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmailer

Hola buenas tardes estimados amigo de stackoverflow les escribo con intenciones de que me puedan ayudar necesito introducir dos variables php entre una comillas para enviar un correo de prueba con phpmailer en el texto del mensaje pero no lo he logrado.

Muestro mi código.

```php
 $mail->addAddress($row_datos['direccioncorreo'], $row_datos['nombre']);     // Add a recipient

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Recuperacion de Contraseña';
    $mail->Body    = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">   <tr>     <td>Estimado usuario:  $row_datos['nombre']   </td>   </tr>   <tr>     <td>Usted a solicitado una recuperacion de contraseña para su usuario por lo que anexamos al siguiete correo la contraseña correspondiente para su inicio de secion:</td>   </tr>   <tr>     <td>CONTRASEÑA |   $row_datos['pas001']   </td>   </tr>   <tr>     <td><p>Recuerde que el siguiente correo eelectronico es totalmente confidencial, por lo tanto agradecemo su no divulgacion.</p>     <p>No responda este correo electronico.</p>     <p>El correo electronico a sido enviado a traves de nuestro robot en linea.</p>     <p>&nbsp;</p>     <p>Atentamente.</p>     <p>Plataforma Automatizada.</p></td>   </tr> </table>';
```

Pero no me funciona las variables causan error en la linea del body y causa que los correos no salgan.

esta es una de las variables que estoy introduciendo en la linea del body:

$row_datos['direccioncorreo'] 
$row_datos['nombre']

Tengo poca experiencia pero si me podrían indicas como hacerlo aunque sea con un ejemplo practico o un indicio de exactamente como buscar se los agradecería.

Saludos cordiales.

synapsevzla.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que concatenar las partes donde aparecen variables, haciendo algo así:

```
' ... texto... '.   $row_datos['pas001']. ' ... más texto ';
```

Prueba así:

```
$htmlBody='
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Estimado usuario:'. $row_datos['nombre'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Usted ha solicitado una recuperación de contraseña para su usuario por lo que anexamos al siguiente correo la contraseña correspondiente para su inicio de sesión:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CONTRASEÑA |'. $row_datos['pas001'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Recuerde que el siguiente correo eelectrónico es totalmente confidencial, por lo tanto agradecemos su no divulgación.</p>
                <p>No responda a este correo electrónico.</p>
                <p>El correo electrónico ha sido enviado a través de nuestro robot en línea.</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>Atentamente.</p>
                <p>Plataforma Automatizada.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

$mail->Body = $htmlBody;
```

De paso, se corrigieron algunos errores que había en el texto.

Si quieres conocer mejor cómo funcionan las comillas en PHP, puedes consultar la pregunta:

- [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)

Answer (score 0):

te dejo la solucion lo que tenias que hacer es concatenar las comillas simples entre las variables. es recomendable utilizar variables pre definidas para enviar emails.

Solucion:

```
<?php
 $mail->addAddress($row_datos['direccioncorreo'], $row_datos['nombre']);     // Add a recipient

 //Content
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
 $mail->Subject = 'Recuperacion de Contraseña';
 $mail->Body    = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td>Estimado usuario: '.$row_datos['nombre'].'
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Usted a solicitado una recuperacion de contraseña para su usuario por lo que anexamos al siguiete correo la contraseña correspondiente para su inicio de secion:</td> 
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>CONTRASEÑA | '.$row_datos['pas001'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Recuerde que el siguiente correo eelectronico es totalmente confidencial, por lo tanto agradecemo su no divulgacion.</p> 
<p>No responda este correo electronico.</p>
<p>El correo electronico a sido enviado a traves de nuestro robot en linea.</p>  
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Atentamente.</p>
<p>Plataforma Automatizada.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: Estimado matias muchas gracias también había tratado de hacer eso pero me falto el punto que colocaste al final pruebo y te aviso como me funciono ya había colocado el punto como lo vi en el manual de php para la variable entre comillas pero al final de la variable no volví a colocar el punto.