# Cómo puedo hacer este where con variable $_SESSION

Tags: php

Tengo este código pero me está dando error en esta parte **$_SESSION['$idusuario']**, no me reconoce el cierre del **"]"**. aquí está todo mi codigo.

```
session_start();
class Consultas{

    public function totalacumulado(){
    if ($_SESSION['idusuario']==1) {
    $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(MontoAcumulado),0) as total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
    else{
        $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['$idusuario']";
          return ejecutarConsulta($sql);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías asignar el valor de `$_SESSION['$idusuario']` a otra variable.

Comment: el problema es aqui en el else   $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['$idusuario']"; no me reconoce la ]

Comment: por eso mismo no puedes usarlo de esa manera, puedes asignarlo a `$idu=$_SESSION['$idusuario'];` y luego has `$sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $idu";`

Comment: este es todo mi codigo ya hice eso pero me da error al asignar una variable

Comment: <?php 
require "../config/Conexion.php";
session_start();
class Consultas{
 public function __construct(){
}
 public function totalacumulado(){
 if ($_SESSION['idusuario']==1) {
 $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(MontoAcumulado),0) as total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones";
 return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
 }
 else{
  $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['$idusuario']";
       return ejecutarConsulta($sql); 
  }
 }
}
 ?>

Answer (score 4):

Hay varios problemas aquí:

```
"SELECT ... WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['$idusuario']"
                                       ^          ^ 1) Las comillas simples 
                                                    dentro de comillas dobles
                                                    son problemáticas

                                         ^          2) idusuario es una clave de array
                                                       no una variable para usar $
```

1. Estás dentro de una cadena que empieza y termina por `"` y no puedes meter sin más comillas simples dentro de ella <sup>1</sup>.
2. Realmente `$_SESSION` es un array como cualquier otro y **estás usando el signo `$` para referirte a la clave `idusuario` de la variable de sesión**. Lo estás confundiendo con una variable.

**Solución:**

Puedes escribir la consulta así simplemente:

```
$sql= "SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION[idusuario]";
```

Nótese que aquí, dado que la cadena está rodeada por comillas `"`, no es necesario usar las comillas simples para referirse a la clave del array como se hace habitualmente.

Otra solución mejor es usar variables:

```
$mIdUsuario=$_SESSION['idusuario'];  # Aquí si usamos las comillas simples
$sql= "SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $mIdUsuario";
```

Debería funcionar de cualquiera de las dos formas.

---

> **Nota sobre la seguridad:**
>
> Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Considera usar
>   consultas preparadas para prevenir ese riesgo.

---

1. Para más detalles sobre esto, ver la pregunta [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967) y las respuestas aportadas en ella.

Comment: sigo teniendo el mismo problema parece que al poner $_SESSION[idusuario] en el where no me lo reconoce

Comment: @jarlispereira si no funciona debe haber otro error en otra parte. ¿Podrías indicar el mensaje de error que da ahora luego de corregir esa parte del código?

Answer (score 0):

Veo de buena manera tu sql, pero veo algo  raro.

```
$sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['$idusuario']";
```

no deberia de ser de esta forma

$sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['idusuario']";

o de ingual forma asignar el  valor dela session  a una variable

```
$id =  $_SESSION['idusuario'];
```

Comment: $sql="SELECT MontoAcumulado AS total_compra FROM acumuladocomisiones WHERE idusuario= $_SESSION['idusuario']"; de esta forma me dice este error. (T_STRING) or variable(T_VARIABLE) OR number

Comment: puedes imprimir tu variable para saber que te esta regresando.