# Como hacer que php lea una dirección que mezcla string y variable?

Tags: php, php7

se que será una pregunta muy sencilla pero me gustaria saber como se haría para que mi web php me lea la ruta del directorio segun string i variable.

Os muestro el codgio:

```
$directorio2= '../packs/pack$i';
```

$i es un contador que contiene un entero, quiero ir a la carpeta ../packs/pack1.
cuando el contador aumente ir al pack2.

Grácias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacer así:

```
$directorio2= '../packs/pack'.$i;
```

Por supuesto tendrás que manejar el valor de $i correctamente por tu lado.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

También se podría hacer uso de las dobles comillas en vez de la simples para delimitar el `string`.

Las variables encerradas en dobles comillas se van a interpretar, mostrándose su contenido en caso de tener conversión a `string`.

```
$i = '1';
$directorio2= "../packs/pack$i";

echo $directorio2;
```

**Salida:**

```
../packs/pack1
```

**Referencia:** [Análisis de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

**Edit**

Con el fin de conseguir una mejor legibilidad se pueden usar llaves para diferenciar la variable del `string`.

```
$i = '1';
$directorio2= "../packs/pack${i}";
    
echo $directorio2;
```

Comment: Usando esta notación, me gusta poner las variables entre llaves para ayudar a la legibilidad.

Comment: Ciertamente ayuda. Lo añado a la respuesta.

Comment: De hecho, esta es la respuesta correcta. La otra también funciona, pero está es la preferida.