# echo dentro de un echo en un while, ayuda con php y html

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

         while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resul)){

           echo "<li><a href=\"{$fila['url']}\">{$fila['nombre']}</a>

           echo <ul class="submenu"> $n['nombre'];</ul>

           </li>";

           }

         ?>
```

Buenas tardes, estoy empezando en php usando html, tengo un problema para realizar un menu dinamico, tengo pensado una barra que es $fila donde me trae el [nombre] de esa opcion (opciones padre), pero tambien quiero crear submenus dentro de esa opción (opciones hijos), revise un tutorial y vi que se crea una clase "submenu" dentro del primer echo, pero el segundo echo me lo toma como texto, entonces quisiera como sacar las opciones de n$[nombre] que son el nombre del los submenus,

Comment: ya intentaste quitando el 2do echo y colocando comillas simples en el 'submenu'?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo interpretar (estoy un poco oxidado en PHP), no quieres que el texto del echo se termine hasta el `</li>`, cierto? Si es así, por qué tienes un echo *dentro* de ese texto? Aparte, si esto es correcto, el texto se corta cuando vas a escribir el `submenu`. Tendría que ser `\"submenu\"`.

En todo caso, eso se ve un poco rough... creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es salir de php y no hacer los echos:

```
<?php
    while (blahblah) {
?>
        <li><a href="blahblah">whatever</a>
          <ul class="submenu">blahblah</ul>
        </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Y, por supuesto, usarías `<?=  ?>` para escribir los valores que necesites. EN mi humilde opinión, queda más ordenado que estar haciendo echos.

Answer (score 0):

La constante mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML produce un código confuso y horrible.

Para escribir un código limpio puedes trabajar dentro de un bloque PHP 100%, concatenando en una variable.

Con este forma de trabajar hay tres claves importantes:

1. Encerrar la cadena dentro de **comillas dobles**
2. Escapar las comillas dobles que sean parte del contenido con `\`
3. En **este caso concreto** es válido omitir las comillas para referirse a las claves de los arrays <sup>1</sup>.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
        #Variable de concatenación
        $html="";
        #Usa un método fetch específico
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)){
           #Se usa .= para concatenar
           #Escapamos comillas que sean parte del contenido
           #No usamos ningún tipo de comillas para las claves de array
           #Ignoro lo que sea $n, lo dejo como lo tenías
           $html.="<li><a href=\"$fila[url]\">$fila[nombre]</a>
                    <ul class=\"submenu\"> $n[nombre]</ul>
                   </li>";
        }
        #Al final del bucle, imprimimos
        echo $html;   
?>
```

Se da por supuesto que las otras partes están construidas adecuadamente. Salvo otros errores, debería funcionar.

---

### Notas

1. Para más detalles consultar la pregunta: [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967) y sus respuestas.