# como agrego correctamente la liga href en php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

que tal estoy buscando la forma de agregar bien la liga de php ya sea que el usuario le di clic o en automatico lo mande

pero no se como editarlo bien para que lo envie y se rediriga a otra pagina en un tab nuevo

que seria este

```
<?php
$mensaje=!empty($_POST['mensaje']) ? $_POST['mensaje'] : NULL;
$numero=!empty($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : NULL;

//aqui agrego un inserte a my databases


 header('Location: https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/$numero/$mensaje/PROG/Cmg5/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0');
    exit;
```

Comment: Cuando hay variables dentro de las cadenas, conviene que rodees todo de comillas dobles, y si hubiera comillas dobles en la cadena, las puedes escapar. Por ejemplo: **`header("Location: https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/$numero/$mensaje/PROG/Cmg5/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0");`** Así debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: md sirvio gracias y disculpa hay forma de agregarle un target blank patra que me abra en otra pestaña

Comment: No es posible con `header` usar target _blank, simplemente porque esto último es una redirección que ocurre del lado del cliente, mientras que `header` es una redirección del lado del servidor. Para ello tendrías que intentar redirigir desde el cliente, con código Javascript por ejemplo. Aunque te recomiendo que no abuses target _blank, a menos que sea justificado su uso.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando hay **variables** dentro de las cadenas, conviene que rodees todo de comillas dobles, y si hubiera comillas dobles en la cadena, las puedes escapar.

Por ejemplo:

```
header("Location: https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/$numero/$mensaje/PROG/Cmg5/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0");
```

Así debería funcionar sin problemas y es la forma más simple. Pues si usas comillas simples, deberás concatenar donde haya variables como `$numero`, `$mensaje`, etc.

Para profundizar en esto puedes consultar esta pregunta [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967).

Comment: No es que convenga, es que hay que utilizarlas.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas no es obligatorio, por ejemplo se puede usar comillas simples, pero en ese caso sería obligatorio *concatenar*, en aquellos putos donde haya variables. Al decir *conviene* quiero decir que la mejor práctica es rodear todo de comillas dobles, pero no es la **única** forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Cierto. Yo me refería a como está en la pregunta, todo en una cadena. Un saludo.