# ¿Como puedo hacer bien un array en PHP y obtener los datos con while o for en otro PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, while

El codigo que estoy intentando es el siguiente:

```
 index.php
 
 include(conexion.php);
 mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
 $result = $conexion->query("SELECT titulo, texto FROM db WHERE id = 'libros'");
 $filas = array();
 while($campos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $filas[] = $campos;
 }
 $miarray = json_encode($filas); 
 echo "_______________________________________________";
 echo $miarray;
 echo "_______________________________________________";
 envio la variable $miarray con AJAX en POST 'prueba' y recibo en ejecuta.php
 

 ejecuta.php

 $prueba = $_POST["prueba"];
 aquí me gustaría poder hacer algo como esto:

 while($campos = ($prueba)) { 
 $titulo = $prueba['titulo'];
 $texto =  $prueba['texto'];
 }
 echo "<h1>" . $titulo . "</h1>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<p>" . $texto . "</p>";
```

Aquí me debería arrojar todas las columnas ¿como lo puedo solucionar? o ¿como puedo hacer un While u otra forma de arreglo para obtener el resultado?

Comment: Está sintaxis `$prueba[$i]->$texto` no corresponde a arrays sino objetos, por favor trata de ser más claro en tu pregunta

Comment: @BetaM Listo, ya hice la corrección (edición) en la pregunta. Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener ese resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en tu código de `ejecuta.php`.

### Primero

Esta forma de leer un array no es correcta:

```
while($campos = ($prueba)) {
```

Lo que haces ahí es simplemente igualar el array `$prueba` a `$campos`, abriendo además un bucle infinito, porque el `while` no tendría un modo de detenerse dado que no estás leyendo un recurso ni nada parecido hasta que se agote (como suele ocurrir por ejemplo cuando lees resultados de una consulta a la base de datos con algún método `fetch`).

### Segundo

Estás imprimiendo las variables asignadas fuera del bucle. Significa que, en caso de funcionar, sólo se van a imprimir los datos de la última fila.

### Solución

Si `$prueba` es un array válido, puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
$prueba = $_POST["prueba"];

foreach ($prueba as $fila) { 
    echo "<h1>$fila[titulo]</h1><p>$prueba[texto]</p>";
}
```

Simplemente, es como si dijéramos: *cada fila de `$prueba` se llamará `$fila`*. Luego, imprimimos cada valor **dentro del bucle**.

También, para optimizar el código, dado que no se requiere portar el dato a ninguna otra parte, sino mostrarlo *in situ*, es mejor hacer un `echo` directamente, pues no tiene sentido guardar variables en este caso.

#### Cambios en la sintaxis

Si observas, he usado una sintaxis de conveniencia: en el `echo` he usado una sola cadena rodeada de comillas dobles y para extraer los datos de `$fila` no he puesto la notación tradicional `$fila['titulo']` o `$fila["titulo"]`, sino simplemente `$fila[titulo]`, etc... Esto es totalmente válido<sup>1</sup> y se puede usar para evitar verbosidad innecesaria en el código. De todos modos, si quieres hacer `echo` separados por cada valor, como lo tenías, puedes hacerlo.

Otra cosa es que el `<br>` seguido de una etiqueta de encabezado (`h1`) sobra. Las etiquetas de encabezado provocan de por sí un salto con respecto a la línea siguiente. Si quieres espacios adicionales es mejor que los manejes a través de reglas CSS.

---

1. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultas la pregunta: *[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)*.