# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me aparece ese error en la linea de codigo 8 que es esta:

```
$reg = mysqli_query($conexv,"SELECT id FROM ventas WHERE sim = $_POST['ingresarsim']") or die (mysqli_error($conexv));
```

Intente poner el  $_POST['ingresarsim'] como una variable, al hacer eso me presenta otro error y pienso que es mas sencillo dejarlo así como esta y arreglar el error de sintaxis

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- > No debes pasar por ningún motivo valores dinámicos de forma directa en tus sentencias SQL
- Si tu consulta espera para constituirse valores dinámicos, entonces debes usar sentencias preparadas
- En lugar de la variable de forma directa, deberás pasar un marcador de posición: `?`
- Usarás el método `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` para pasar 3 valores:

  - La consulta
  - El tipo de dato del valor dinámico
  - La variable donde se encuentra el valor dinámico
- Al final procedes a ejecutar la consulta con: `mysqli_stmt_execute`

Quedando de esta forma:

```
$ingresarSim = $_POST['ingresarsim'];

$reg = mysqli_prepare($conexv, "SELECT id FROM ventas WHERE sim = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
mysqli_stmt_execute($reg);
```

**Referencias**

- [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [tipos de datos para los parámetros dinámicos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters)

Comment: Ahora me aparece este error:
Undefined index: ingresarsim in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRABAJO\index.php\variable.php

ingresarsim la tengo en la siguiente linea de codigo:
<input type="text" name="ingresarsim">
include ("variable.php");

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta la estructura del form desde donde mandas a la variable, pues el error que indicas no tiene que ver con mi respuesta

Comment: Una pregunta, en mysqli_stmt_bind_param, en el segundo parametro pusiste una "i", me puedes explicar el porque de esto? y por que una "i"?

Comment: Ya leíste el segundo enlace de mi redpuesta?, Ahí está la respuesta del uso de i

Comment: Ohhh muchísimas gracias