# ¿Cómo hacer redireccionamiento con una variable en php (header location)?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un enlace/redireccionamiento a otra pagina con php (con header location) y que el nombre de esa pagina este en una variable.
La variable será leida de una base de datos.
Según el usuario haya leido ya la página anterior el redireccionamiento será a pagina1.php o pagina2.php, etc

Para simplificar, el numero de la siguiente página estará en $numero_siguiente_pagina y querria hacer algo asi (que no me funciona):

```
<?php
$numero_siguiente_pagina=2;
$siguiente_pagina='pagina' . $numero_siguiente_pagina . ' .php';
header('Location: "$siguiente_pagina"');
?>
```

¿Es posible hacer esto en php o header location necesita siempre un valor constante, tipo :

```
<?php
header("Location: pagina1.php");
?>
```

Comment: Perfecto, así funciona estupendamente. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar variables dentro de **cadenas rodeadas por comillas dobles** sin mayor dificultad.

En tu caso, lo más simple sería esto:

```
$numero_siguiente_pagina=2;
#Aquí también simplificamos, poniendo todo entre comillas dobles
$siguiente_pagina="pagina$numero_siguiente_pagina.php";
header("Location: $siguiente_pagina");
```

No funcionaba porque usabas comillas simples, en cuyo caso tendrías que ponerlo concatenando:

```
$numero_siguiente_pagina=2;
#Aquí había un espacio de más, antes del punto
$siguiente_pagina='pagina' . $numero_siguiente_pagina . '.php';
header('Location: '.$siguiente_pagina);
```

Así también funcionaría, pero las concatenaciones hacen el código más largo y complicado de analizar.

Para más detalles sobre el tema de las comillas, puedes consultar la pregunta: [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)

### Recomendación

Te recomiendo que evites el uso de nombres de variables tannnn largos. Quizá adoptar una convención de nombre en inglés daría internacionalidad a tu código y lo haría más simple.

Comparemos estas dos líneas:

Este bloque tendría 122 caracteres de sólo código.

```
$numero_siguiente_pagina=2;
$siguiente_pagina="pagina$numero_siguiente_pagina.php";
header("Location: $siguiente_pagina");
```

Este bloque tiene 84 caracteres de sólo código... 38 caracteres menos en un pequeño trozo y ganamos en legilibidad.

```
$next_number=2;
$next_page="pagina$next_number.php";
header("Location: $next_page");
```