# Se puede añadir una clase a un tag desde un echo php?

Tags: php, html

Quizas suena un poco absurda la pregunta, pero hace poco que he empezado con php y me gustaria mostrar un tag [p] y cuando aparezca este tenga unos estilos. Pero cuando lo convierto en string para mostrarlo con el echo da error con tema de las comillas.

```
echo "<p class="alerta">Revisa el error</p>";
```

Hay alguna manera de poner una clase manualmente sin tener error con el echo? Gracias

Comment: `echo "<p class='alerta'>Revisa el error</p>";`

Comment: Muchas gracias, un error muy de novato.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con comillas dobles, escapando con \ las comillas dobles interiores. Yo lo hago así, cuando dentro hay variables, así evito concatenar con el punto. Por ejemplo: `echo "<p class=\"alerta\">Revisa el error</p>";` Sobre todo es útil en casos así: `$msg="Revisa el error";` Si quieres usar `$msg` dentro de la cadena: `echo "<p class=\"alerta\">$msg</p>";`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con comillas dobles, escapando con `\` las comillas dobles interiores.

Yo lo hago así, cuando dentro hay variables, así evito concatenar con el punto. Por ejemplo, para tu caso, sería simplemente esto:

```
echo "<p class=\"alerta\">Revisa el error</p>";
```

Ahora supongamos que quieres meter información de una o más variables dentro:

```
$msg="Revisa el error";
```

Si quieres usar `$msg` dentro de la cadena, simplemente haces esto:

```
echo "<p class=\"alerta\">$msg</p>";
```

Además, podríamos decir que el contenido HTML es el estándar, que usa `"` para indicar los atributos de los elementos.

---

### PD

Si quieres profundizar un poco más sobre el uso de las comillas en PHP, puedes consultar esta pregunta, los casos allí expuestos y su(s) respuesta(s): [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967) .

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @A. Cedano es bastante buena para escapar comillas simples. Yo también tengo otro tipo de recomendaciones.

PHP es un lenguaje que permite la utilización de comillas simples `'` para imprimir cadenas de caracteres.

Es decir, en lugar de tener esto:

```
echo "<p class="alerta">Revisa el error</p>";
```

Tendríamos algo así:

```
echo '<p class="alerta">Revisa el error</p>';
```

Si notas, el hecho de usar `'` comilla simple para imprimir cadenas string en php resulta más sencillo y cómodo cuando se necesita por alguna razón ocupar comillas dobles `"` dentro de esta cadena.

Puedes encontrar más información detallada sobre cuándo usar comillas dobles `""` y cuándo ocupar comillas simples `'` [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles).

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de poner comillas dobles en el *class* pon comillas simples:

```
echo "<p class='alerta'>Revisa el error</p>";
```