# Problema al listar un usuario en mi web php

Tags: php, mysql

he intentado mostrar datos mediante una búsqueda de código pero no me muestra nada o lo peor, me muestra errores.

Este es mi código de php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnValidar'])){
    $val = $_POST['txtValidar'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT codMatri_alumno, 
                             dni_alumno,
                             nombres_alumno,
                             apellidos_alumno,
                             especialidad_alumno 
                      from alumno 
                      where codMatri_alumno LIKE '".$val."' LIMIT 1");
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>$res[codMatri_alumno]</td>";
            echo"<td>$res[dni_alumno]</td>";
            echo"<td>$res[nombres_alumno]</td>";
            echo"<td>$res[apellidos_alumno]</td>";
            echo"<td>$res[especialidad_alumno]</td>";               
        echo"</tr>";
    }
  }
?>
```

No quiero mostrar todas las columnas de mi base de datos, por eso la selección en el SELECT, además de solo querer mostrar un solo registro, por eso el LIMIT 1.

Comment: Noto un problema grande de fondo, pero antes de responder comenta: ¿qué versión de PHP usas?

Comment: ¿Estás usando esto o fue un error de dedo: `mysql_query`?

Comment: En una parte usas `mysql` y en otra `mysqli`. [MySQL quedó obsoleto tras la actualización de PHP 5.5.0](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: En tanto me haces saber la versión que usas he de comentarte a grandes rasgos otro error es aqui: `echo"<td>$res[codMatri_alumno]</td>";` la clave del array asociativo que deseas recuperar debe ir entrecomillas, en este caso simples

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la parte donde imprimes `$res`, pues estás imprimiendo un array en un string, y esto no es posible

> Notice: Array to string conersion in..

Puedes definir una variable por cada dato que necesitas imprimir y usar la variable en tu string

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnValidar'])){
    $val = $_POST['txtValidar'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT codMatri_alumno, 
                             dni_alumno,
                             nombres_alumno,
                             apellidos_alumno,
                             especialidad_alumno 
                      from alumno 
                      where codMatri_alumno LIKE '".$val."' LIMIT 1");
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $codMatri_alumno = $res["codMatri_alumno"];
        $dni_alumno = $res["dni_alumno"];
        $nombres_alumno = $res["nombres_alumno"];
        $apellidos_alumno = $res["apellidos_alumno"];
        $especialidad_alumno = $res["especialidad_alumno"];
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>$codMatri_alumno</td>";
            echo"<td>$dni_alumno</td>";
            echo"<td>$nombres_alumno</td>";
            echo"<td>$apellidos_alumno</td>";
            echo"<td>$especialidad_alumno</td>";               
        echo"</tr>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Estás haciendo esto:

```
$res[codMatri_alumno]
```

1. Se imprimirá *$res*, es un array, por lo que dará un *Notice*
2. Podrías aplicar llaves, es decir

```
{$res['codMatri_alumno']}
```

Esto quiere decir que una parte del string donde estén las llaves será interpretada como variable

Ya que, si hacemos

```
print "$holaMundo";
```

Se imprimirá la variable $holaMundo, y a menos que quieras renombrar tus variables, puedes ponerle llaves

```
print "{$hola}Mundo";
```

---

En una parte usas MySQL y en otra MySQLi, también puede ser error de eso...

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query ) : mixed
```

La forma correcta es la siguiente, entonces quedaría

```
mysqli_query($db, "query...");
```

Si usas una versión inferior a PHP 5.5, deberías ver [las funciones mysql() en el manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió para arreglarlo.
El detalle es que me sale todo en una sola línea.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que aún deberían mejorarse en tu código.

1. En las consultas deberías hacer una verificación de los datos esenciales. En este caso, para que la consulta funcione el dato que viene en `$_POST['txtValidar']` es **esencial**, por tanto, deberías verificarlo. Aquí he usado un ternario para ello y luego lo he incluido en el `if`. He cambiado el nombre de la variable, no me fiaría de un nombre como `$val`, que podría ser candidato algún día a palabra reservada.
2. Cuando usas comillas dobles en las cadenas puedes concatenar todo dentro, incluyendo comillas simples, por ejemplo, en el caso del `LIKE`, eso te evita romper la concatenación con un punto, lo cual hace el código más ilegible.
3. Si vas a leer una sola fila, no necesitas un bucle (en este caso `while`). Los métodos `fetch` de por sí mueven el puntero hacia el primer registro, los bucles sólo son útiles cuando hay varias filas, para vaciar el puntero.
4. Si concatenas tu salida, en vez de hacer `echo, echo, echo, echoooo`  es más útil y el código queda más claro. Por ejemplo, te da la ventaja de tener tu variable a mano para un posible `return` hacia la vista o para controlar un simple flujo de salida en el mismo contexto con una misma variable. Otra ventaja aquí es que, si usas comillas dobles para esa cadena (a la que he llamado `$outPut`), puedes sacar los valores de arrays sin necesidad de usar comillas de ningún tipo<sup>1</sup>, como estaban en tus `echo` en el código original presentado en la pregunta.

Si aplicamos todo lo dicho tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
  /* Aplicamos lo dicho en (1) */
  $txtValidar=!empty($_POST['txtValidar']) ? $_POST['txtValidar'] : NULL;
  if(isset($_POST['btnValidar']) && $txtValidar){
    /* Aplicamos lo dicho en (2) */
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT codMatri_alumno, 
                             dni_alumno,
                             nombres_alumno,
                             apellidos_alumno,
                             especialidad_alumno 
                      from alumno 
                      where codMatri_alumno LIKE '$txtValidar' LIMIT 1");

    /* Aplicamos lo dicho en (3)*/
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    /* Aplicamos lo dicho en (4) */
    $outPut="<tr>";
            $outPut.="<td>$res[codMatri_alumno]</td>";
            $outPut.="<td>$res[dni_alumno]</td>";
            $outPut.="<td>$res[nombres_alumno]</td>";
            $outPut.="<td>$res[apellidos_alumno]</td>";
            $outPut.="<td>$res[especialidad_alumno]</td>";               
     $outPut.="</tr>";
  } else {
     $outPut="No se postearon datos válidos";
  }
  echo $outPut;
?>
```

### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Finalmente, advierto que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para blindar tu programa contra este tipo de ataques que podría ser de muchos niveles y causar verdaderos estragos en tu base de datos e incluso en tu servidor o equipos conectados.

---

**Notas:**

1. Para más detalles sobre esto y sobre el tema de las comillas en general, puedes consultar esta pregunta: ***[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)***