# Consulta MYSQL y PHP Concatenar variables

Tags: php, mysql

Soy nuevo programando en PHP y Mysql y no puedo resolver algo que creo es sencillo pero necesito de su ayuda. Tengo un formulario con fecha y hora de inicio y también fecha y hora de termino.

```
$fecha1 $fecha2 $hora_1 $hora_2
```

Tengo la siguiente query, donde intento mostrar todos los registros que fueron ingresados entre las fechas y horas que se seleccionen, pero no se como concatenar para que lo que busque tenga el formato '2020-12-12 18:00', pero lo que tengo no me muestra nada.

SELECT * FROM servicio_de_salud_antofagasta WHERE estatus = 1 and
(fecha_solicitud BETWEEN '$fecha1.' '.$hora_1' AND '$fecha2.' '.$hora_2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP puedes usar **comillas dobles** para la cadena en general y en ese caso las variables pueden ir tal cual sin necesidad de seguir concatenando dentro de la cadena, usando además sin ningún problema comillas simples para los criterios, espacios, etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM servicio_de_salud_antofagasta a 
          INNER JOIN carr c on a.id_carrera=c.id 
          INNER JOIN establecimiento est on a.id_establecimiento=est.id 
          INNER JOIN servicio ser on a.id_servicio=ser.id 
          INNER JOIN sector sec on a.id_sector=sec.id 
          INNER JOIN tipo_practica t on a.tipo_practica=t.id 
       WHERE a.estatus = 1 
           AND (a.fecha_solicitud BETWEEN '$fecha1 $hora_1' 
           AND '$fecha2 $hora_2')";

echo $sql;
```

Para más detalles puedes consultar la pregunta: [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias, me funciono..

Answer (score 0):

Basta con poner un punto entre variables & asignar el resultado a una nueva variable, es decir:

```
$res = 'La fecha es: '. $fecha1 . $fecha2 . $hora_1 . $hora_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> CONCAT_WS()

Ejemplo

```css
 SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE genero = "Mujer" AND fechaRegistro 
BETWEEN CONCAT_WS(' ','2021-01-01','10:01') AND CONCAT_WS(' ','2021-01-05','10:01')
```