# Error PHP no deja acceder a la variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

No me deja acceder a la variable y da este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING).

He intentado añadir "" y '' pero no funciona. ¿Alguna solución?

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )) {
    $consulta4 = "SELECT SUM(Precio) as Importe FROM productos WHERE idProducto IN (
         SELECT idProducto 
         FROM linea_pedido 
         WHERE idpedido=.'$columna['idpedido']'
    )";
    $resultado4 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta4 );
    $columna3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado4 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado, no estás concatenando bien en esta parte de la consulta SQL:

```
    WHERE idpedido=.'$columna['idpedido']'
```

El punto rompería la cadena que empezaste con las dobles comillas, por tanto tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
     WHERE idpedido='".$columna['idpedido']."'
```

Aunque este estilo, es mucho más claro, y es totalmente válido:

```
     WHERE idpedido='$columna[idpedido]'
```

Esto es posible porque en una cadena dentro de comillas dobles, puedes acceder a las claves de los arrays sin usar comillas simples (ver *[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)* para más detalles).

Por otra parte, el bucle `while` no está cerrado al final.

Prueba de este modo:

```
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )) {
    $consulta4 = "SELECT SUM(Precio) as Importe FROM productos WHERE idProducto IN (
         SELECT idProducto 
         FROM linea_pedido 
         WHERE idpedido='$columna[idpedido]'
    )";
    $resultado4 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta4 );
    $columna3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado4 );
  }
```

Ten en cuenta que si `idpedido` es de tipo numérico, es mejor omitir las comillas simples:

```
         WHERE idpedido=$columna[idpedido]
```

Comment: El bucle esta cerrado más abajo. La primera opción funciona. Gracias por la ayuda.