# Para no repetir tanto "echo" ¿qué puedo usar?

Tags: php, php7, echo

¿Qué puedo usar para no repetir tantas veces **echo**?

```
    echo "Nombre: ".$responsearr['nombre']."<br/>";
echo "Tipo Identificacion: ".$responsearr['tipoIdentificacion']."<br/>";

echo "<br/>Regimen <br/>";
echo "Codigo: ".$responsearr['regimen']['codigo']."<br/>";
echo "Descripcion: ".$responsearr['regimen']['descripcion']."<br/>";

echo "<br/>Situacion <br/>";
echo "Moroso: ".$responsearr['situacion']['moroso']."<br/>";
echo "omiso: ".$responsearr['situacion']['omiso']."<br/>";
echo "estado: ".$responsearr['situacion']['estado']."<br/>";
echo "Administracion Tributaria: ".$responsearr['situacion']['administracionTributaria']."<br/>";

echo "<br/>Actividad <br/>";
echo "Estado: ".$responsearr['actividades']['0']['estado']."<br/>";
echo "Tipo: ".$responsearr['actividades']['0']['tipo']."<br/>";
echo "Codigo: ".$responsearr['actividades']['0']['codigo']."<br/>";
echo "Descripcion: ".$responsearr['actividades']['0']['descripcion']."<br/>";
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Puedes utilizar el operador de concatenación `.=` 
Por ejemplo 
`$html_code = "Nombre: ".$responsearr['nombre']."<br/>"; 
$html_code .= "Tipo Identificacion: ".$responsearr['tipoIdentificacion']."<br/>";
echo $html_code;`

Comment: En tu caso, quizás es mejor utilizar HEREDOC https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc. échale un vistazo, te simplificaría mucho, pero tienes que aplicarlo bien (muchas veces por temas de salto de línea no funciona y es porque no hemos aplicado bien las reglas)

Answer (score 8):

Puedes concatenar todo en una variable. Esto permite escribir un código limpio y más fácil de depurar.

Otra ventaja es que si rodeas la variable de comillas dobles, no necesitas concatenar más y puedes meter dentro variables y claves de array (sin usar las comillas identificadoras para las mismas en este caso). Es decir, que puedes hacer cosas como esta sin ningún problema:

```
$outPut="Lorem $unaVariable dolor $unArray[unaClave] sit amet";
```

Podemos meter `$unaVariable` directamente dentro de la cadena `$outPut`, así como el valor que haya en `unaClave` de `$unArray` usando la sintaxis sin comillas, en vez de usar la forma habitual `$unArray['unaClave']` o `$unArray["unaClave"]` (para más detalles sobre esto consultar la pregunta *[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)*).

Aplicando lo dicho anteriormente, podrías escribir tu código de este modo:

```
$outPut="
    Nombre: $responsearr[nombre]<br/>
    Tipo Identificacion: $responsearr[tipoIdentificacion]<br/>
    <br/>Regimen <br/>
    Codigo: $responsearr[regimen][codigo]<br/>
    Descripcion: $responsearr[regimen][descripcion]<br/>

    <br/>Situacion <br/>
    Moroso: $responsearr[situacion][moroso]<br/>
    omiso: $responsearr[situacion][omiso]<br/>
    estado: $responsearr[situacion][estado]<br/>
    Administracion Tributaria: $responsearr[situacion][administracionTributaria]<br/>

    <br/>Actividad <br/>
    Estado: $responsearr[actividades][0][estado]<br/>
    Tipo: $responsearr[actividades][0][tipo]<br/>
    Codigo: $responsearr[actividades][0][codigo]<br/>
    Descripcion: $responsearr[actividades][0][descripcion]<br/>";

echo $outPut;
```

Answer (score -1):

Es válido usar una variable donde cargues todo el contenido.
otro tip si necesitas usar ciclos ya sea FOR o While, puedes ponerlo así

`$outPut .="";`

Por ejemplo seria así:

```
$outPut = "Primer lote de informacion";
```

ciclo  `{ $outPut .="Informacion creada por el ciclo"; }`

esto lo puedes emplear en creacion de tablas o listas.

```
echo $outPut;
```