# Tengo un error con mi loggin, no me carga lo que tengo en mi SELECT

Tags: php

[image: Espero puedan ayudarme]

Este es el login de sesión, no me carga el apartado de select, tengo todo correcto al parecer en mi código PHP, alguien me podría hechar una mano, adjunto mi código PHP, gracias de antemano! :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Éste es mi código PHP gracias amigos!

```
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <select name="codigo_sucursal" class="form-control" data-placeholder="--seleccionar sucursal" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?
                                        $query_prov = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT suc_cod, suc_descri
                                        FROM sucursal
                                        ORDER BY suc_cod ASC") or die ('Error'.mysqli_error($mysqli));
                                        while ($data_prov = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_prov)){
                                            echo "<option value=\"$data_prov[suc_cod]\">$data_prov[suc_descri]</option>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Xmaname, comparti la escritura de tu codigo. Tal vez sea tu error $data['suc_cod'] el indice con comillas.

Comment: Siempre es bueno agregar el código como texto en lugar de imagen, eso facilita el poder copiar y pegar. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar -Patrick Arguello, ahora mismo adjunté mi código, sigo con el mismo problema. No puedo resolverlo aún, espero retorno, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te sale algo en los logs de PHP? Esos índices de `$data_prov` sin comillas parecería que no va a pintar lo que esperas. No sería algo como `<option value=\"$data_prov['suc_cod']\">$data_prov['suc_descri']</option>"`

Comment: Hola como está Alfabravo, no, ahora mismo probé con tu código, pero sigue igual :/

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, lo que OP hace aquí es totalmente válido: `echo "<option value=\"$data_prov[suc_cod]\">$data_prov[suc_descri]</option>";`, porque en un contexto de comillas dobles puedes suprimir las comillas en las claves del array en el primer nivel un nivel (ver el **Caso 3** expuesto en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)). Aquí estamos más bien ante un problema básico de depuración y de código débil (OP debería verificar si esa consulta devuelve filas para entonces pasar a construir el `select option`)

Comment: Que se me note que hace años no toco un script PHP fuera de SOes. :) Gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 0):

No deberías programar de una forma ingenua, pensando que siempre todo funcionará del modo esperado. En el contexto de tu código varias cosas podrían fallar y tu tarea como programador debe ser también prever esos fallos y dar una respuesta adecuada a los mismos.

En este caso concreto no puedes pasar a construir los `option` sin más, puede no haber conexión a la base de datos, puede que la consulta SQL sea errónea, puede que no arroje filas.

Te propongo esto:

```
if ($mysqli) {
    $sql="SELECT suc_cod, suc_descri FROM sucursal ORDER BY suc_cod ASC";
    if ( $query_prov = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) ) {
    <?
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <select name="codigo_sucursal" class="form-control" data-placeholder="--seleccionar sucursal" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
    <?php                    
        while ( $data_prov = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_prov) ) {
            echo "<option value=\"$data_prov[suc_cod]\">$data_prov[suc_descri]</option>";
        }
    ?>
                </select>
        </div>
    <?php  

    } else {
        #Modificar por errror personalizado en producción
        echo "Error en la consulta:".mysqli_error($mysqli); 
    }                 
} else {
    echo "No hay conexión";
}
```

Como podrás apreciar aquí, el `select ... option` sólo pasará a crearse cuando se haya verificado que la consulta pueda arrojar algún resultado. En los casos contrarios se emitirán mensajes de error de consulta fallida o de no conexión... te toca a ti adaptar dichos mensajes a un contexto más específico, como un `div`  dedicado a los errores por ejemplo.