# ¿Cómo mostrar dos variables de un arreglo de php en el atributo id de una etiqueta de html5?

Tags: php, html5

tengo una inquietud y hasta el momento no he encontrado mucha información talvez ustedes me puedan ayudar ya que mediante `php` realizo una consulta y obviamente imprimo el resultado de la misma por html, un ejemplo de lo que tengo en código sería:

```
<?php
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name");
?>
<html lang="es">
   .
   . 
   .
   <body>
      <div>
         <?php
         while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
         //print_r($prod);
         ?>
            <div class="item">
               <img src="<?php echo $prod['...'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod['...'] ?>" id="<?php echo $prod['...'] ?>" onclick="javascript: clave()">
               <div class="texto_trj">
                  <div class="nombre_producto">
                     <h2 id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION'] ?>" onclick="javascript: claveFDP()"><?php echo $prod['...'] ?></h2>
                     </div>
                     <div class="precio_producto">
                        <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                        <label><?php echo $prod['...'] ?></label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="caracteristicas">
                        <ul id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION']?>"></ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <?php
               }
               ?>
            </div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

quisiera saber si es posible, y si lo hay, como implementarlo ya que mi objetivo sería en la `id de la clase caracteristicas` poner si es posible

```
id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION'],echo $prod['DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA'] ?>"
```

pero esto ya lo pondría en la etiqueta `<div>` previa

hasta el momento intente ejecutar esto pero en pantalla me salió el error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "echo" y de igual manera con la función `print` pero no entiendo puedo concatenar estas 2 variables y utilizar el caracter `,`

Gracias de antemano por su atención

Answer (score 1):

```
id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION'],echo $prod['DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA'] ?>"
```

Esto solo debes cambiarlo al orden que quieres, **no hay que hacer 2 echos**, solo 1 y concatenas el caracter que quieras.

```
id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION'].','. $prod['DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA'] ?>"
```

Entonces, asi podemos concatenar la variable A seguida de una COMA y seguida de la variable B.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto:

- Concatenando con el punto:

  ```
  id="<?php echo $prod['DESCRIPCION'].' , '. $prod['DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA'] ?>"
  ```
- En una sola cadena. Para ello debes usar comillas dobles y puedes/debes omitir las comillas para las claves de array (sólo permitido en el primer nivel) <sup>1</sup>:

  ```
   id="<?php echo "$prod[DESCRIPCION] , $prod[DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA]" ?>"
  ```
- Con `printf()` aquí pondrías marcadores para los valores de la variables y la coma la pones directamente en la cadena:

  ```
   id="<?php printf("%s , %s",$prod['DESCRIPCION'], $prod['DESCRIPCION_SUBCATEGORIA']) ?>"
  ```

De todos modos, te recomendaría evitar la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML y construir todo en un entorno PHP. Esta mezcla puede producir código confuso e ilegible.

---

1. Ver el **Caso 3** en la pregunta *[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)*.