# Rellenar option select php pdo

Tags: php

Estoy intentando rellenar un select. Hago el include en el html para cargar los datos, pero no me carga el select con los datos.
Como ya hago la conexión en el html ya no la meto en el php para obtener los datos. La página es sencilla, solamente tiene que conectarse, ejecutar la consulta y traer los datos.

```
$statement = $cnn->prepare("Select id_dato, dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4 from tabla order by dato1");

$statement->execute();

while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo "<option value=" . $row["id_dato"] . ">" . $row["dato1"] . "</option>";
}
```

Pues no me muestra nada en el select

Answer (score 1):

Problema con las comillas! fallo mío!

```
$statement = $cnn->prepare('SELECT Select id_dato, dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4 from tabla order by dato1');

$statement->execute();


    while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value=" . $row['id_dato'] . ">" .$row['dato1'] . "</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Para evitar esto, puedes hacer lo siguiente: `echo "<option value=\"$row[id_dato]\">$row[dato1]</option>";` Cuando usas comillas dobles, puedes omitir las comillas de identificadores de array de un solo nivel (ver lo expuesto en el **Caso 3** de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)), poniendo todo en la misma cadena y escapando las comillas interiores con \. Esto permite un código más claro con menos líos entre comillas dobles y simples y puntos de concatenación.

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano ! si, a veces si no te fijas bien te lías con comillas, escapados, puntos...