# Variable entre llaves con PHP

Tags: php

Ayer estaba programando y cometí un error al llamar una variable, y el resultado fue correcto. Dejo el código y me gustaría saber porque pasa eso, si es nuevo de PHP 8 o quizás ya existía? En que cambia este método?

```
<?php

$nombre = "Pepe";

echo "Hola {$nombre}";
// respuesta: Hola Pepe    

?>
```

Gracias y disculpen si la pregunta es tonta.

Comment: Eso es correcto. Es una de las 4 formas que hay para imprimir contenido de una variable. Ojo, existe ya un RFC para deprecar esa forma en php8.2 y quitarlo en php9. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dollar_brace_string_interpolation

Comment: @Jakala, en ese enlace se menciona que se van a mantener `"$variable"` y `"{$variable}"` (con el `$` dentro de las llaves), pero se va a eliminar `"${variable}"` (con el `$` fuera de las llaves). Es decir, se mantiene la [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: Aquí te dejo una respuesta ya hace tiempo detallado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles/93234#93234

Comment: De hecho, yo acostumbro a usar las llaves para tener claro que estoy metiendo una variable. Aunque prefiero usa printf o sprintf. Otra cosa, recuerda que la variable sólo es interpretada en una cadena delimitada por comillas dobles, con comillas simples no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay pregunta tonta y no se trata de un error, sino de una característica de PHP, para poder incluir e interpretar variables en cadenas usando [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) y, en mi opinión, la principal ventaja es que te permite incluir directamente elementos de arreglo y propiedades de objeto sin recurrir a concatenación.

```
echo "Hola {$nombre}";
// Es lo mismo que
echo "Hola $nombre";
```

Con variables simples no hay tanto problema, pasando a algo más complicado: Sin usar llaves, debes concatenar para usar elementos de arreglo o propiedades de objeto dentro de una cadena:

```
// Con elementos de arreglo
echo "Hola " . $usuario['nombre'] . " " . $usuario['apellido'] . " bienvenido";
// Con propiedades de objeto
echo "Hola " . $usuario->nombre . " " . $usuario->apellido . " bienvenido";
```

Encerrar las variables entre llaves te ayuda a evitar la concatenación:

```
// Con elementos de arreglo
echo "Hola {$usuario['nombre']} {$usuario['apellido']} bienvenido";
// Con propiedades de objeto
echo "Hola {$usuario->nombre} {$usuario->apellido} bienvenido";
```

Mi opinión (sí, otra vez), es más fácil codificar de esta forma y queda más legible.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, entiendo perfectamente lo que dices y comparto al 100% tu opinión. Ahora voy a tomar las cosas desde otra perspectiva. Este año termino la prepa y creí que había visto todo en PHP, pero veo que siempre voy a estar aprendiendo algo nuevo.

Comment: Añadir también. Que la interpolación en comillas dobles funciona también con `${bar}` ejemplo echo `"hola ${test}";`. Y como nota extra que hay rfc para revisar esta funcionalidad para próximas versiones https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dollar_brace_string_interpolation