# Concatenar variables php con con código html (Problema con las comillas simples y dobles)

Tags: php, html

intentando imprimir código HTML, concatenando las variables dentro una funcion onClick.
No consigo ordenar bien las comillas para que funcione.

```
echo  "<button onclick='myFunction('" . $_id . ",'" . $_tipus . "'" . "," . "'" . $_desc . ")'  style='width:10px;border:none;margin-right:50px;'>
      <img src=" . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/modify.png' . " style='width:25px;margin-right:20px;' alt='Submit Form'>
</button>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(1," despatx','la="" reserva="" serà="" anual')'="" style="width:10px;border:none;margin-right:50px;">
```

OUTPUT DESEADO:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(1,'despacho','la reserva sera anual')"  style="width:10px;border:none;margin-right:50px;">
```

Comment: Y si intentas usar otro tipo de comillas para que no te martilices la vida concatenando cadenas? Puedes usar este tipo de comillas ``. En las veces que lo he usado me ha ayudado a escapar tanto las comillas simples como las dobles.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple es que uses `printf`, que te permite poner un marcador donde irían los valores, pasando los valores al final.

Algo así más o menos:

```
printf("<button onclick=\"myFunction(%s,%s,%s)\") style=\"width:10px;border:none;margin-right:50px;\">
      <img src=\"%simg/modify.png\" style=\"width:25px;margin-right:20px;\" alt=\"Submit Form\">
</button>",$_id,$_tipus,$_desc,plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
```

Si quieres guardar para concatenar con otra cosa, puedes usar `sprintf`, que funciona del mismo modo, con la diferencia de que guardarías el resultado en una variable.

Para más detalles [consulta la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php).

### Más sobre comillas y concatenaciones

En el código he implementado una práctica que me parece la más coherente, consiste en usar comillas dobles en todo momento. Esto tiene una gran ventaja: que puedes poner variables dentro de la cadena. Esto es útil en casos en que no uses `printf` o `sprintf`. En ese caso, las comillas dobles que sean parte de esa cadena las puedes escapar de este modo: `\"`.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer esto:

```
$redClass="button-red";
$str="<button id=\"btnOne\" class=\"$redClass\">Botón rojo 1</button>";
// ... más código
$str.="<button id=\"btnTwo\" class=\"$redClass\">Botón rojo 2</button>";
echo $str;
```

Para más detalles sobre esto consulta la pregunta: *[Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)*.

### Advertencia sobre malas prácticas

En tu código estás usando dos malas prácticas que deberías evitar:

- Las funciones in-line se consideran una mala práctica
- Poner código CSS in-line también se considera una mala práctica, es mejor usar clases y definir las reglas de estilo en un archivo `.css`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Lo tendré en cuenta!

Comment: @AleixRoca revisa la respuesta editada. He agregado otra información y un enlace a otra pregunta que podría ser de utilidad en un futuro. Saludos.